# why do i get a garbage value when i try to print array[size]?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 
 int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
 cout<<a[5]<<endl; 
return 0; 
}
```

why do I get a garbage value instead of "out of range" error?

Comment: valid indices are `0` till `4`. There is no 6th element in the array. What did you expect to get as output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: Because you don't pay for what you don't use

Comment: Because this is how the language works. Most compilers can check array bounds for you if you ask (look up "sanitizers"), but it's slower and hard to do in general, so usually it's disabled.

Comment: read about [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You will encounter it more often and not always it is so obvious to spot as in this case

Comment: You would with `std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` followed by `a.at(5);`

Comment: C++ have no range checking at all for arrays. To get an "out of range" exception you must use a `std::vector` or `std::array` and use its `at` function which have range-checking.

Comment: On the line before `cout<<a[5]<<endl;`, add this line:  `if (5 > 4) throw std::logic_error("out of range");`

Comment: In general C++ opts for speed over pretty much everything unless you explicitly ask for something other than speed.